# How to determine "unmet dependencies" when attempting to install MAME?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, mame

I am trying to install MAME, but I keep getting this error message:

[image: Picture]

What packages is it talking about?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install mame` in the terminal and copy/paste the results in your question.

Comment: You'll see the subsequent message if you run the command in terminal (the GUI is only displaying the first line of multiple lines)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu software center will not print the unmet dependencies. Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

If it failed, it will detail show the unmet dependencies.